# Prove $[Mf,P] = MfP - PMf$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

**Note That**

$\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R} / 2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$

$H^2 (\mathbb{T}) = \{ f \in L^2| \hat{f} (n) =0, \forall n <0 \}$.

$P: L^2 (\mathbb{T}) \to H^2(\mathbb{T})$

Prove the following:

1-For $f \in C(\mathbb{T}), [M_f,P] = M_fP - PM_f \in K(L^2 (\mathbb{T}))$.

Hint: First show $[M_f,P] \in F(L^2 (\mathbb{T}))$ for a trigonometric polynomial $f$. Then use the fact that the map $C(\mathbb{T}) \ni f \mapsto [M_f,P] \in B(L^2 (\mathbb{T}))$ is continuous.

2-For $f \in C(\mathbb{T})$ and $g \in L^\infty (\mathbb{T})$, $Tfg - Tf \,Tg \in K(L^2 (\mathbb{T}))$.

Hint: $PMfgP - P Mf P Mg P = PMf(I-P)MgP$.

3-For $f \in C(\mathbb{T})^{-1}$, $Tf \in FR(H^2 (\mathbb{T}))$.

Hint: Use (2) and Atkinson's theorem.

I faced this problem in my functional analysis but I have no idea how start or using the hint. Could you please show some steps about how to tackle this problem.

Comment: can you explain what is $P$?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn $P$ is a projection from $L^2 (\mathbb{T})$ to Hardy space.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: If $f=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}a_j\epsilon_j$ then $P(f)=\sum_{j>0}a_j\epsilon_j$?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn yes. I edited the question though.

Comment: can you explain what is $T$?

Comment: Toeplitz operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by $Mf$ you mean the multiplication operator. I will denote it by $M_f$ instead.

As it is known, the trigonometric polynomials are dense in $C(\mathbb{T})$ with the supremum norm. Now let $z:\mathbb{T}\to\mathbb{C}$ be the inclusion function, $z(\zeta)=\zeta$. Suppose that we have shown that, for any $j\in\mathbb{Z}$, the commutator $[M_{z^j},P]$ is a compact operator.

If $f$ is a trigonometric polynomial, then $f=\sum_{j=-N}^Na_jz^j$ and one can easily see that $M_f=\sum_{j=-N}^Na_jM_{z^j}$. Thus
$$[M_f,P]=\sum_{j=-N}^Na_j[M_{z^j},P]$$
and this is a compact operator, as a linear combination of compact operators.

Now if $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ and $\varepsilon>0$, then we can find a trigonometric polynomial $g\in C(\mathbb{T})$ with $\|f-g\|_\infty<\varepsilon$. Then,
$$\|[M_f,P]-[M_g,P]\|=\|M_fP-PM_f-M_gP-PM_g\|=\|[M_f-M_g, P]\|\leq$$
$$\leq2\|P\|\|M_f-M_g\|\leq2\varepsilon$$
This shows that we can approximate the operator $[M_f,P]$ with compact operators, so the operator $[M_f,P]$ lies in the closure of the compact operators. But the compacts are a closed set, so $[M_f,P]$ is itself compact.

So all we have to do now is show that $[M_{z^j},P]$ is a compact operator. Note that $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ has the standard ONB $\{\epsilon_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}$ where $\epsilon_j(\zeta)=\zeta^j$. Now the projection $P$ is defined by $P(\epsilon_j)=0$ if $j\leq0$ and $P(\epsilon_j)=\epsilon_j$ for $j>0$. Also, it is very easy to see that the Multiplication operator $M_{z^k}$ acts as $M_{z^k}(\epsilon_j)=\epsilon_{j+k}$ for all $k,j\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Now we show that $[M_{z^k},P]$ is compact for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, for all $j\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have that
$$[M_{z^k},P](\epsilon_j)=M_{z^k}P(\epsilon_j)-PM_{z^k}(\epsilon_j)=M_{z^k}P(\epsilon_j)-P(\epsilon_{j+k})$$
Let's assume that $k\geq0$.

If $j>0$, then $j+k>0$ and the above becomes
$$M_{z^k}P(\epsilon_j)-P(\epsilon_{j+k})=e_{j+k}-e_{j+k}=0.$$
If $j\leq0$ then we distinguish two cases: if $j<-k$, so $j+k<0$, then the above becomes
$$M_{z^k}P(\epsilon_j)-P(\epsilon_{j+k})=0-0=0.$$
On the other hand, if $j\in\{-k,-k+1,\dots,-1,0\}$, then $j+k>0$, so
$$M_{z^k}P(\epsilon_j)-P(\epsilon_{j+k})=0-\epsilon_{j+k}=-\epsilon_{j+k}.$$
So we see that the only elements of the orthonormal basis $\{\epsilon_j\}$ that can be mapped to non-zero functions are only those $\epsilon_j$ for $j\in\{-k,-k+1,\dots,-1,0\}$
Therefore, the image of the operator $[M_{z^k},P]$ has finite dimensional range, so this operator is finite rank, thus compact.

Similarly one handles the case for $k<0$.

### edit

(2) $T_{fg}-T_fT_g=PM_{fg}P-PM_fPM_gP=PM_fM_gP-PM_fPM_gP=PM_f(I-P)M_gP$.
Now since $P$ is a projection, $P(I-P)=(I-P)P=0$, we have that
$$PM_f(I-P)M_gP=(PM_f-M_fP)(I-P)(M_gP-PM_g)=-[M_f,P]\cdot(I-P)\cdot[M_g,P]$$
and this is compact because of (1) and the fact that the compact operators are an ideal in $B(H)$.

(3) If $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ is invertible (which means that $f\neq0$ everywhere, so $g=\frac{1}{f}$ is its well-defined inverse) then by (2) we have that
$I-T_fT_g$ and $I-T_gT_f$ are compact operators. By Atkinson's theorem we have that $T_f$ is a Fredholm operator.

Comment: Thank you so much. What an elegant proof. In case you will not prove the other parts could you please write some comments so I follow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MathGin Which part is unclear to you? I have left unproven only very elementary claims that are completely straightforward

Comment: Your proof was crystal clear but I meant the other parts of the question, I think you have not noticed them because of the edit i had made.

Comment: Oh, okay. I will have a look at them.

Comment: @MathGin I have edited my post. If everything is clear to you, consider accepting so the post is marked as answered.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124878/discussion-between-mathgin-and-justdroppedin).